# Vertical-Align in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Hey,
Has somebody a good solution to clean the vertical-align:middle bug with select-box in IE7 ?
All my elements are correct display in table-row, but input-elements are keep doing on top..

It's the selectbox it make problems

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be solved here already: [Table item vertical-alignment change when adding control inside TD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938217/table-item-vertical-alignment-change-when-adding-control-inside-td)